# NgRx Effects; Dispatching an Action from CatchError, while also returning the Error itself

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an effect which catches the HttpErrorResponse, but since there's also a global error handler, I dont want to *catch* the error, I want to *tap* it.

**The .catchError should both return the Error for the Interceptor, as well as dispatch the addItemFailure action**

```
addItem$ = createEffect((): Observable<Action> => {
  return this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemActions.addItem),
    exhaustMap((action) => {
      return this.apiClient.addItem(action.itemModel).pipe(
        map((response) => ItemActions.addItemSuccess({ response })),
        catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return throwError(() => exception);
          return of(ItemActions.addItemFailure({ exception }));
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
});
```

Above of course does not work because of the double return, but it  shows what I'm trying to achieve. Using one of them works, but I need them both to work.

I've tried:

```
catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  this.store.dispatch(ItemActions.addItemFailure({ exception }));
  return throwError(() => exception);
}),
```

or

```
catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  return throwError(() => {
    this.store.dispatch(ItemActions.addItemFailure({ exception }));
    return exception;
  });
})
```

But that doesn't work somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with a little help from @ali-ataf:

```
catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) => {
  of(EMPTY).pipe(
    tap(() => this.store.dispatch(ItemActions.addItemFailure({ exception }))),
    switchMap(() => throwError(() => exception)),
  )
)
```

Full Effect now looks like:

```
addItem$ = createEffect((): Observable<Action> => {
  return this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemActions.addItem),
    exhaustMap((action) => {
      return this.apiClient.addItem(action.itemModel).pipe(
        map((response) => ItemActions.addItemSuccess({ response })),
        catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          of(EMPTY).pipe(
            tap(() => this.store.dispatch(ItemActions.addItemFailure({ exception }))),
            switchMap(() => throwError(() => exception)),
          ),
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try chaining the 2 observables you want to execute as follows:

```js
addItem$ = createEffect((): Observable<Action> => {
  return this.action$.pipe(
    ofType(ItemActions.addItem),
    exhaustMap((action) => {
      return this.apiClient.addItem(action.itemModel).pipe(
        map((response) => ItemActions.addItemSuccess({ response })),
        catchError((exception: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          return of(ItemActions.addItemFailure({ exception })).pipe(
            first(),
            switchMap(() => throwError(() => exception))
          );
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
});
```

Comment: I tried, but as soon as you add `switchMap(() => throwError(() => exception))`, the Action does not work anymore.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal Weird, at the time it reaches the switchMap, the action should be already been executed, can you maybe share a reproducible example for the case?

Comment: Doesn't the Action wait for the pipe to complete first? Which maybe never does, because of the Error somehow closes/aborts is.